# Luxury watches database

Tags: data-request

perhaps someone knows where can I find a public database for watches and their reference numbers? Timepieces are quite standardized and I would be very interested on checking it out for a personal project.
Something like this would be helpful:

http://www.watchtime.com/watch-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like http://watchbase.com/watches

i am looking for something similar for woocommerce projects i am working on.

Answer (score 4):

I have found my answer but it is unfortunately a vague one, I had to resort to reviewing manually (scraping) some of the watch selling websites there are but a lot of post-data quality control has to be done.

Comment: What tool are you using to scrape? I've used rvest / selectorgadget with good success.

Comment: so why don't you post that data for others to use? you can always add it to the open data se datahub.io repository

Comment: good idea yes , will do

Comment: @johan855 did you publish your set of data?

Comment: I didn't in the end, I used https://watchbase.com/ as suggested by warmax.